# One line input with 100% and button in CSS

Tags: css

I have this html:

```html
<textarea>One line</textarea>
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
```

I want `textarea { with: 100%; }` but with one line with buttons.
How these three elements arranged in a single line that would textarea maximum space occupied?
How to do it in CSS?

Comment: If you want the textarea to have the height of one line of text, use input.

Comment: Like this: http://cl.ly/image/1m2d2i2M0W0s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only [targeting Chrome<del>, Firefox</del> and Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility), you can use `flex`:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhbtG/

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea rows="1"></textarea><button>One</button><button>Two</button>
</div>
```

```css
div.container {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:row;
    flex-direction:row;
}
div.container > textarea {
    -webkit-flex:1 1 auto;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
div.container > button {
    -webkit-flex:0 1 auto;
    flex:0 1 auto;
}
```

[More about compatible situation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

---

**Edit**:

If you really need this, and really need to target other browsers, here's an ugly solution that uses `<table>` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhbtG/1/

Comment: What about IE?

Nothing to do with Firefox?

Comment: @AntonElfet Sorry that I don't have an IE 10 right now to test, but if you really need to target various browsers, the `table` solution I updated might be more helpful.